# Trying to install ruby in Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, osx-mountain-lion

So i'm new with this. I'm trying to install ruby on my mac with mountain lion.
im following this guide:http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

when I put "brew doctor" I get this lot of warnings:

```
$ brew doctor
Warning: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework detected
This can be picked up by CMake's build system and likely cause the build to
fail. You may need to move this file out of the way to compile CMake.
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.dylib
Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libusb.la
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp.la
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libusb.pc
Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libusb.a
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp.a
```

What should I do? What's happening?

Comment: I haven't really used Homebrew, but it looks like the instructions you're following have you install RVM.  In that case, it's simple enough to use RVM to install Ruby versions (Google it).  Your Mac should already come with Ruby though.  What happens when you do `which ruby` in the terminal?  Do you know which version of Ruby you want to have?

Comment: it just says /usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you manage your ruby installations with either [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [RBENV](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) it will make your life much easier to manage different versions, upgrades, etc.

Comment: Thanks, what of those you recommend? and how do i implement it?

Comment: @pbelt In each of the links you'll find a very comprehensive guide on how to install and manage your ruby installations.

Comment: Thanks! im following that RVM link

Answer (score 1):

Use [RVM](https://rvm.io/). RVM allows you to install and manage multiple versions of Ruby on the same machine.

You can follow the instructions [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) to install RVM, and instructions [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-install_ruby) to install Ruby. The second link is an excellent beginners guide to get going with ruby-on-rails by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac probably comes with Ruby 1.8.7.  I like some of the features in 1.9.x, and they've recently released 2.0.0, so you may wish to upgrade.  However there's no point doing work if you ain't gonna need it, so first decide whether you need a different version of Ruby right now.  (And verify your current version with a `ruby -v`).

Assuming you need a new version, RVM and rbenv are two tools that make installing and managing (a.k.a. switching between) various Rubies and their versions very easy.  Some people don't like RVM because it does some strange things (like override the definition of `cd` - change directory), but I find it simpler to use, and doesn't require you to remember to rehash every time.  Read up on it and decide for yourself.

If you want to use RVM:

1. Install it (Google to find out how).
2. Make sure to source the script that it tells you to do in the output during the installation.
3. Start using it: `rvm install <version>` (e.g. `rvm install 1.9.3`), `rvm use <version>` (to switch between versions), `rvm list` (to see which Rubies you have installed), etc.

Answer (score 0):

RVM has more online resources so it's be a good choice since you're starting. Pay attention to the error logs in your console and Google them, you'll probably see some quite accurate results (as the ruby install issues are common).